# how to set multiple auto connection in sql server management studio 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have 5 SQL server DB engine in 5 diffrente server like as "10.255.133.51 & 10.255.133.48 & ....."

I want to set auto connection for these servers and when i open SQL server management studio in my PC they ready to use without needs to make connection

Is there any way to do this ?????